# Derivative of the maximum of two random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

For any two real numbers $a$ and $b$ and any two random variables (with no mass points in their distributions) $x$ and $y$, why is it that the derivative of $E[\max\{a+x,b+y\}]$ with respect to $a$ is $\Pr(a+x>b+y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning: The statement is not true as you have asked it.** We will only be able to show that the derivative exists at points $a$ where $P[a+x=b+y]=0$. I give a counterexample below for when this condition is not met.

Let $|h_n| \downarrow 0$. Consider that for all $\omega \in \Omega,$ for all $n$ large (depending on $\omega$), we will have have $$\max\{a+h_n+x(\omega),b+y(\omega)\}-\max\{a+x(\omega),b+y(\omega)\} $$

$$
= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
h_n, & a+x(\omega)>b+y(\omega)\\
0,&  a+x(\omega)< b+y(\omega)\\
h_n 1_{h_n>0},&a+x(\omega)=b+y(\omega)
\end{array} \right.
$$

Thus the difference quotient satisfies
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{h_n}(\max\{a+h_n+x(\omega),b+y(\omega)\}-\max\{a+x(\omega),b+y(\omega)\} ) = 1_{a+x(\omega) > b+y(\omega)}
$$
for all $\omega$ where $a+x(\omega)\neq b+y(\omega)$.
We see that the derivative will exist at $a$ if $P(a+x=b+y)=0$ by taking expectations and applying dominated convergence (the difference quotients are bounded!).  Doing so gives $$\partial_a E[\max\{a+x,b+y\}] = E[1_{a+x > b+y}] = P[a+x > b+y].$$

Note that we did not need independence of $x$ and $y$.

Example of the derivative not existing if $P[a+x = b+y]>0$. Take a fair 2-coin flip space, with $x$ being the indicator of the first flip being heads and $y$ being the indicator of the second flip being heads. Take $a=b=0$. Of course $P[x=y]=\frac12$.
Then the difference quotient turns out to look like
$$
\frac{\max (0,h)+\max (0,h+1)+\max (1,h)+\max (1,h+1)-3}{4 h}
$$

$\hskip 1.5 in$[image]

as function of $h$.

In fact,

> `Expectation[
>    Max[x + a, y], {Distributed[x, BernoulliDistribution[1/2]], 
>     Distributed[y, BernoulliDistribution[1/2]]}]`

gives
$$
\frac{1}{4} (\max (0,a)+\max (0,a+1)+\max (1,a)+\max (1,a+1))
$$
which looks like

$\hskip 1.5 in$[image]

Thus the derivative does not exist for $a=0$.

Comment: You are right that independence does not play a role. I however fail to follow the first part of your derivations. When a+x>b+y we know that max{a+x,b+y}=a+x (2nd term in your initial expression) but how can we also conclude that max{a+x+h,b+y}=a+x+h hence get h as a difference? h need not be positive (even if it converges to zero). Likewise, for the opposite situation, when a+x<b+y we know that max{a+x,b+y}=b+y (2nd term in your initial expression) but how can we also conclude that max{a+x+h,b+y}=b+y hence get zero as a difference? h need not be negative (even if it converges to zero).

Comment: I see the update. Thanks for taking the time. Yes, I agree with the issue of when there is a positive probability that the two RV are equal, I should have assumed that away e.g. x and y have no mass points.

Comment: If $a+x>b+y$ then $\max\{a+x+h,b+y\} = a+x+h$ for all $|h|<|(a+x)-(b+y)|$. Since $h_n \to 0$, for each $\omega$ we may choose $n$ large enough that this condition is met. The same argument applies for the opposite direction.

Comment: Good. I acknowledge that you wrote "for n large enough" at the very beginning so the argument was implicit and I appreciate your clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation):
\begin{align}
& \lim_{\Delta a\to0}\frac{\operatorname E(\max\{a+\Delta a+x,b+y\}) - \operatorname E(\max\{a+x,b+y\})}{\Delta a} \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname E \left(\lim_{\Delta a\to0}\frac{ \max\{a+\Delta a+x,b+y\} - \max\{a+x,b+y\}}{\Delta a}\right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname E\left( \operatorname E\left( \left.\lim_{\Delta a\to0}\frac{ \max\{a+\Delta a+x,b+y\} - \max\{a+x,b+y\}}{\Delta a} \,\right|\, I \right)\right)
\end{align}
where
$$
I = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }\max\{a+x,b+y\} = b+y \\[8pt] 1 & \text{if } \max\{a+x,b+y\} = a+x  \end{cases}
$$
If $b+y$ is the maximum, then the conditional expected value is $0$.

If $a+x$ is the maximum, then the conditional expected value is $1$.

So the outer expected value is the expected value of a random variable that is $1$ with probability equal to $\Pr(a+x>b+y)$ and $0$ with the complementary probability.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works. My mistake was to first apply the law of iterated expectation and then attempt to take the derivative at which point "a" was showing up all over the place: E[max{a+x,b+y}]=E[a+x|a+x>b+y]Pr(a+x>b+y)+E[b+y|a+x<=b+y]Pr(a+x<=b+y). I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your inner limit may not exist if $P[a+x=b+y]>0$ (and this provides a counterexample to the question). See my answer.

Comment: My answer works for continuous distributions.  I haven't looked closely enough yet at what to do with discrete parts of distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Assume first that $b=0$ and that $x=0$ almost surely, and let $u(a)=E(\max(a,y))$. The identity $\max(a,y)=y+(a-y)^+$ and the fact that $a\mapsto(a-y)^+$ is differentiable to the right with derivative $a\mapsto\mathbf 1_{a\geqslant y}$ and differentiable to the left with derivative $a\mapsto\mathbf 1_{a\gt y}$ show that $u$ is differentiable to the right with derivative $a\mapsto\mathbb P(a\geqslant y)$ and differentiable to the left with derivative $a\mapsto\mathbb P(a\gt y)$.

In the general case, start from the identity $\max(a+x,b+y)=x+\max(a,b+y-x)$ and use the case above with $b+y-x$. Thus, the function $a\mapsto E(\max(a+x,b+y))$ is differentiable to the right with derivative $a\mapsto\mathbb P(x+a\geqslant b+y)$ and differentiable to the left with derivative $a\mapsto\mathbb P(x+a\gt b+y)$.

Finally, the function $a\mapsto E(\max(a+x,b+y))$ is differentiable exactly at the points $a$ such that $\mathbb P(x+a\geqslant b+y)=\mathbb P(x+a\gt b+y)$, that is, where $\mathbb P(x+a=b+y)=0$.