# How to show lower semicontinuity: differentiability $\rightarrow$ continuity $\rightarrow$ lower semicontinuity?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, derivatives, continuity, semicontinuous-functions

Take $G: \mathbb{R}^M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $G(a)\equiv \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(\max_{k\in \{1,...,M\}}V_k+a_k)$ for any $a\equiv (a_1,...,a_M)\in \mathbb{R}^M$,  where:

**A1:** $V\equiv(V_1,...,V_M)$ is an $M\times 1$ random vector with absolutely continuous distribution and support on an open subset $\mathcal{V}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^M$ with positive Lebesgue measure.

($\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}$ denotes expectation using probability measure $\mathbb{P}$).

I want to show that $G$ is **lower semicontinuous**.

---

My attempt:

1) Notice that, **under A.1**, for any $y\in \{1,...,M\}$ 
$$
\mathbb{P}(V_y+\alpha_{xy}\geq V_k+\alpha_{xk}\text{ }\forall k=1,...,M)= \frac{\partial \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P} } (\max_{k\in \mathcal{Y}} V_k+\alpha_{k})}{\partial \alpha_{y}}
$$
See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434115/derivative-of-the-maximum-of-two-random-variables) for a proof. This shows that $G$ is differentiable at any $a\in \mathbb{R}^M$.

2) Differentiability implies continuity on $\mathbb{R}^M$.

3) Continuity implies lower semicontinuity on $\mathbb{R}^M$.

**Correct?**

Comment: What has the vector $\mu$ have to do with anything? Presumable $E \|V\| < \infty$? Surely $g$ is continuous?

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks: 1) $\mu$ typo, sorry; 2) does existence/finiteness of first moment follow from A.1? 3) I think $G$ continuous  follows from differentiability?

Comment: Take $M=1, V_1(\omega) = {1 \over \omega}$ for $\omega \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity and continuity implies semi continuity

Comment: Thank you very much. Is your answer confirming my attempt above? Sorry I am new to this topic

Comment: Well, you need to ensure that the expectation exists, so you need another assumption. That differentiability implies continuity and continuity implies semi continuity is straightforward to prove in general, not just for $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is essentially the Leibniz formula with some attention to detail since the $\max$ function is not differentiable everywhere.

Let $\psi(t) = \max(t_1,...,t_n)$, and note that $\psi$ is Lipschitz with rank one
and the set of points $E$ where $\psi$ is not differentiable has Lebesgue measure
zero.

Assume that $E \|V\| < \infty$ so that the relevant expectations exist.

Let $\phi(x,a) = \psi(x+a)$ from which we get $|\phi(x_1,a_1) -\phi(x_2,a_2)| \le \|x_1-x_2+a_2-a_2\|$.

In particular, note that for any fixed $a$, we have
$|{\phi(x+h,a) - \phi(x)}| \le \|h\|$ and that $E_a = \{ x | (x,a) \mapsto \phi(x,a) \text{ is not differentiable with respect to } a \}$ has Lebesgue measure zero.

Since $V$ has an absolutely continuous distribution, we see that
$P\{ \omega | V(\omega) \in E_a \} = 0$. (This is what makes the following approach work.)

Then ${G(a+ t e_k) - G(a) \over t} = \int {\phi(V(\omega), a+t e_k)-\phi(V(\omega), a) \over t}dP(\omega)$, and from an application of the dominated convergence theorem we get
${\partial G(a) \over \partial a_k} = \int {\phi(V(\omega), a) \over \partial a_k}dP(\omega)$, and hence
${\partial G(a) \over \partial a} = \int {\phi(V(\omega), a) \over \partial a}dP(\omega)$.

It is straightforward to show that a differentiable function is continuous ([Proving differentiable function is continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/938952/27978)).

If $G$ is continuous at $a$ then it follows that if $a_k \to a$, then
$\liminf_k G(a_k)= G(a)$ from which lower continuity follows.